# Invoke freeze my Windows form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, invoke, begininvoke

I'm trying to do my first multithread-windows form app and i have 1 important problem.
I know that i have to use Invoke or BeginInvoke in my thread to change RichTextBox in my form, but my UI just freezing when i'm trying to do it,while console is printing correctly my results.

```
     class MyThread
    {
        public MyThread()
        {

        }


        public void Run()
        {
            byte[] tmp;
            while (true)
            {

                // lock (sem1)
                Monitor.Enter(sem1);
                {
                    if (end)
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(sem1);
                        break;
                    }
                        tmp = inp.ReadNr();

                    if (inp.End())
                        end = true;
                }
                if(inOrder)
                Monitor.Enter(sem2);
                Monitor.Exit(sem1);

                bool p = CSL.checkNr((byte[])tmp.Clone());
                Monitor.Enter(sem3);
                if(inOrder)
                Monitor.Exit(sem2);
                {
                    outp.WriteNr(tmp, p);
                    //win.richTextBox2.AppendText(String.Join("", tmp) + '\n');
                    win.richTextBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
                    {
                        win.richTextBox2.AppendText("wtf");
                    }));
                }
                Monitor.Exit(sem3);

            }
        }
    }
```

"win" is object of my class Form1. I can't deal with it...

EDIT:

```
    static public void loading()
    {
        outp = new oFile();
        Thread[] thr = new Thread[nrThreads];
        for (int a = 0; a < nrThreads; a++)
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(new MyThread().Run)).Start();
        //new MyThread().Run();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.loading();
    }
```

Comment: Is the `Run` method being run on a background thread or the UI thread?

Comment: As a side note, using `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` directly rather than the `lock` statement is unusual and probably a bad idea unless you really know what you're doing.  For instance, if your code between `Enter` and `Exit` throws an exception, the object will be left in a locked state.

Comment: @adv12 I just edited my post how i'm running my threads. UI thread is running method which is creating and starting my threads.

Comment: What does `Program.loading()` do?

Comment: It's creating and starting threads.

Comment: So your button click hangs the program because it ends with `Console.ReadKey`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ding ding ding!  (I wouldn't have noticed that myself.)

Comment: Basically what you did was stop the message loop that was processing messages for the thread that owns the form. BeginInvoke works by posting a message to that thread which eventually gets processed by that message loop. Everything stopped working when you did a Console.ReadKey, had nothing to do with threads or begininvoke, although they were victims of the same problem. Also, you should look at async/await as an alternative to full multithreaded programming, somewhat different and somewhat easier.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is this line in `Program.loading`:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This stops the main GUI thread in its track, so let's see what happens now:

1. Messages posted to the main GUI thread won't get processed (because you're not returning back to the message loop)
2. BeginInvoke from different threads won't get processed, because they work by posting a message to the same message queue that the main GUI thread is processing (which has now halted)
3. Until you press a key (assuming this is even possible), everything will stop. You'll notice that paint messages to the form won't get processed, and eventually the form will fade out and get the "Has stopped responding" text.

So remove that line of code and at least your program should not stop dead in its tracks like before.

---

Having said that, I urge you to try simpler examples to begin with. Your interleaved, manual, handling of multiple monitors leaves me thinking you're at the very start of learning about multithreaded programming, and have started with some complex gears that need to interlock quite accurately to work correctly.

Instead I would ask you to look at `async / await`, new keywords added in C# 5 to handle asynchronous programming. Though asynchrony and multithreading is not the same thing, nor does either imply the other, asynchronous programming usually gets you most of the way towards a responsive UI that won't freeze while waiting for things.